# Implement a view detail page in jsp

Tags: jsp

Hello everyone I have a school project and I have no idea what I am doing.

```
<c:forEach var="recipe" items="${recipeResults}" varStatus="roop">
          <tr>
            <td width="20%">${recipe.name}<script>var model=${recipe.name}; </script></td>
            <td>
              <img src = "${recipe.pictureAddress}" class = "img-rounded center-block"  width="240">
            </td>
            <td width="60%">${recipe.description} <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="viewDetail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</button></td>
          </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

It works for the list all recipes for user but when user click the view detail button I dont know how can keep this specific recipes and then show all information about this recipe.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="getModal(this)" data-description="${recipe.description}">View</button>
```

use `data-attribute` for all what you need

```
function getModal(el) {
    $("#description").val($(el).data("description"));
    ...

    $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .But actually I dont understand where to put the function getModal(el)... part .

Comment: in your script .js file ,,   or in the same page <script></script>

Comment: <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><script> function getModal(el) {
          $("#description").val($(el).data("description"));
          $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
        }</script></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>